# impossible nullpointer exception at calling member function from onWindowFocusChanged

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

please help to understand a strange nullpointer exception, which seems to happen only on specific devices (currently reported only from different tablets, e.g.: Nexus-7, Asus, ...).

The nullpointer exception occurs while calling the current activity's member function from an other member function:

```
10-22 13:50:09.190 E/AndroidRuntime(4445): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-22 13:50:09.190 E/AndroidRuntime(4445): java.lang.NullPointerException
10-22 13:50:09.190 E/AndroidRuntime(4445): at com.plasmobit.CosmicPatrol.ActLogBook.onWindowFocusChanged(SourceFile:194)
10-22 13:50:09.190 E/AndroidRuntime(4445): at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onWindowFocusChanged(PhoneWindow.java:2366)
10-22 13:50:09.190 E/AndroidRuntime(4445): at android.view.View.dispatchWindowFocusChanged(View.java:5740)
10-22 13:50:09.190 E/AndroidRuntime(4445): at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowFocusChanged(ViewGroup.java:851)
10-22 13:50:09.190 E/AndroidRuntime(4445): at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2557)
10-22 13:50:09.190 E/AndroidRuntime(4445): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-22 13:50:09.190 E/AndroidRuntime(4445): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-22 13:50:09.190 E/AndroidRuntime(4445): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
10-22 13:50:09.190 E/AndroidRuntime(4445): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-22 13:50:09.190 E/AndroidRuntime(4445): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-22 13:50:09.190 E/AndroidRuntime(4445): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
10-22 13:50:09.190 E/AndroidRuntime(4445): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
10-22 13:50:09.190 E/AndroidRuntime(4445): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

The code at the line 194 is part of the overridden onWindowFocusChange activity interface.
It is just a call of a parameterless member function:

```
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus)
{
    ...
    doSomeStuff();  // Line: 194
    ...
}

private void doSomeStuff()
{
    ....
}
```

Because we are inside of the onWindowFocusChange function, the this pointer of the ActLogBook activity instance shall be valid, so **how is here a nullpointer exceptoin possible?**

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot reproduce that on any of my test-devices nor on an emulated device.

Comment: are you sure your compiled classes correspond to that source code. (You may have done some change after compiling the application)

Comment: That happens on multiple versions. Always the same place in code.

Comment: Are you looking at the correct version? Maybe the log is for a different version than the source code version (especially since you say it happens on multiple versions), which has a slightly different line number? I'd check the other blocks of code inside the onWindowFocusChange() function to see if there's anything that might cause the NPE, and skip the line 194.

Comment: put some breakpoints in and see what' going on

Comment: * I cannot debug that issue, since I cannot reproduce it on the emulator or on my test devices.
* The line number is correct, even if not: There are only further calls to member functions, without parameters.

The only non-mem-fn-call in onWindowFocusChange is a "if(app.boolMember)" code line. Where "app" is initialized in onCreate() by calling "app= getApplication()". And this exceptions happens only on a few devices (tablets only?).

Comment: @plasmobit did you solve this problem? I have the same problem on some tablets and all Amazon devices

Answer (score 1):

Do not know if you ever figured this out.  I have just encountered a similar issue and since this was the only related Google search thought I would share my findings in case its ever helpful to someone.

I had a reproducible NPE thrown by an argumentless method call to another method on the same instance.  Eventually I thought to try building my apk without Proguard.  Suddenly the stack trace has another line visible at the top from inside the method that had appeared to be throwing the NPE.  It then made a lot more sense.

So try again but leave off Proguard during your debugging.  I guess there must be some bug somewhere that makes Proguard sometimes omit lines of the top of stacktraces.